# In Django, what is a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

I've always been using ForeignKeys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-to-one relationship is a unique relation between two entities in both directions. I.e. for an entity A there exists only one entity B and vice versa.

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) says:

> Conceptually, this is similar to a `ForeignKey`  with `unique=True`, but the "**reverse**" side of the relation will **directly return a single object**.
>
> This is most useful as the primary key of a model which "extends" another model in some way; Multi-table inheritance is implemented by adding an implicit one-to-one relation from the child model to the parent model, for example.